# IntelliSense and enums

Tags: vba

Consider this enum:

```vb
Private Enum colors
    white = 0
    black = 1
End Enum
```

IntelliSense shows black and then white while I'd prefer to see white and then black.
I don't care about the numbers.

Is there a way to customize the enum sequence of the items shown by IntelliSense?

Comment: NO, they are alphabetical.

Comment: Everything in intellisense is alphabetical

Comment: The order of the members in IntelliSense / autocomplete list is irrelevant... type "w" for white, "b" for black...

Comment: Mathieu, the order is not irrelevant: if you type "colors." and then the TAB key it writes the first element (black).  I'd prefer to put the most used one first for writing it faster.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get that ping (use @ to ping someone!) - it *is* irrelevant. `colors.w` completes to `colors.white`, `colors.b` completes to `colors.black`. Ctrl+Space is your friend, not just TAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could prefix the values to create you custom list order.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I'd consider this as best answer if there isn't a better one

Comment: Intellisense alphabetizes everything.  All we can do is write workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

> *if you type "colors." and then the TAB key it writes the first element (black). I'd prefer to put the most used one first for writing it faster.*

Don't use <kbd>TAB</kbd> for completion then. Type `colors.b` then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, and it'll either complete to `Black` (if it's the only member that begins with a B) or moves the autocompletion list selection to `Black` (or whichever alphabetically comes first), given you also have `Blue`, and `Brown`.

Using prefixes merely to control the sort order of members in the IDE's autocompletion list is a rather arbitrary reason for not using clear identifier names and resorting to funky prefixing schemes.

You're not writing code for it to be merely executed. You're reading code for it to be *read*, and maintained.

"It helps me type faster" is actively harmful if your successor has to squint and stop and think and try to make sense of your prefixing scheme - it's distracting, and slows down *reading* the code.

Programming is *at a minimum*, 80% reading, *not* writing. Learn to type faster instead of making *reading* harder than it needs to be.

Comment: if I write "colors.b", both TAB or Ctrl+Space has the same effect of completing with "lack".

Comment: @6diegodiego9 no. it only has the same effect because there's only one enum member that starts with a `B`. If you had `Black`, `Blue`, and `Brown`, TAB completes with the alphabetically-first item; and Ctrl+Space just brings up the completion list.

Comment: I can't reproduce it.  I added "Blue" and while TAB completes it with the first, Ctrl+Space has no effect at all, being the completion list already visible

Comment: Regardless, the point is that a poorly-tooled IDE isn't a valid excuse for butchering your code with such ugly and confusing work-arounds. You write the code once, and then read it many times over - the split-second you "waste" picking the correct identifier isn't worth the multiple split-seconds you, future you, and future maintainers are going to waste making sense of a useless prefixing scheme. If you really like prefixes, know that COM-compliant enum member names start with a 2/3-letter lowercase preffix that acts as a namespace; that's why we have `vbXxxxx` and `msoXxxxx` and `xlXxxxx`.

Comment: Anyway, the speed advantage of TAB over Ctrl+Space is that you can just write "colors." and complete it with the first option in the list.  Furthermore, another advantage with controlling what's the first value in the list is, (by prefixing,) is in having a default/most-used value shown first in the list.  I understand your point that prefixing could distract when reading but as I'm the only programmer looking at my scripts, I believe that my ratio of importance is >50% writing and <50% reading...